# How can I create a tag for a product I love?

Tags: tags, business-intelligence

I love Sisense https://www.sisense.com but unfortunately, the community is still too small to have any presence on SO and I don't have enough points to create a tag. Is there any way to be able to ask and answer Sisense related questions in SO without a tag?

Comment: You have to gain at least 1500 rep to create a tag.... http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: This question belongs, maybe, in meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ but certainly not in main Stackoverflow, as it's not programming related at all.